# Alternative to water as solvent for lithium metaborate?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solvents

I want to prepare a sample of lithium metaborate ($\ce{LiBO2}$) and need to dissolve it for this purpose.

The only solvents I found so far are water and ethanol. In ethanol, one cannot dissolve enough of the solute. Water is quite nice from the solubility point of view, but its high surface tension and tendency of wetting forbids (more or less) its use.

Does anyone have an idea for another solvent as an alternative for water?

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation " latex="" ‎at="" ‎chemistry.se""="), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-‎we-correct-math-formatting) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-‎stuff-here) on how to make your future posts better.‎